# how to integrate django and scrapy and celery?

Tags: python, django, scrapy, celery, django-celery

I have a django project and in its root directory i have a scrapy project that has a spider that should be run every 24 hours and it scrapes provided urls and saves data to a mysql database using django model. i want to shcedule this task using celery beat but i don't know how to integrate django and scrapy project.
this is how my project tree looks like:

```
news-website
|
├──django_app
|  └──models.py
|
├──news-website
|  └──settings.py (and other django auto made files are in this directory)
|
├──manage.py
├──tasks.py
|
└──scrapy_project
   ├──scrapy_project
   |  ├──settings.py
   |  ├──piplines.py
   |  ├──items.py
   |  └──spiders
   |     └──spider.py
   └──scrapy.cfg
```

i tried to create a file in root directory named as tasks.py and i tried to run my spider in it but when i run tasks.py i get this error.

```
from scrapy_project.items import NewsItem
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scrapy_project.items'
```

actually i have this line in my spider.py file:

```
from scrapy_prject.items import NewsItem
```

but since i am running my spider from a script it seems that items file is not accessible for it.
how should i fix this problem and how should i use celery with this project for scheduling my scraper?

Answer (score -1):

you need to create a Django app and modify it with your scrapy code. Then you can add that app to your Django project and use it

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).